# Interrupt Python program deadlocked in a DLL

Tags: python, dll

How can I ensure a python program can be interrupted via Ctrl-C, or a similar mechanism, when it is deadlocked in code within a DLL?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are asking, but there are issues when trying to interrupt (via Ctrl-C) a multi-threaded python process.  Here is a video of a talk about the python Global Interpreter Lock that also discusses that issue:

[Mindblowing Python GIL](http://blip.tv/file/2232410)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2005-October/346842.html) for a couple other suggestions, but there aren't any conclusive answers.

I've encountered the issue several times, and I can at least confirm that this happens when using FFI in Haskell.  I could have sworn that I once saw something in Haskell's FFI documentation mentioning that DLLs would not return from a ctrl-c signal, but I'm not having any luck finding that document.

You can try [using ctrl-break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682541(VS.85).aspx), but that's not working to break out of a DLL in Haskell and I'm doubting it will work in Python either.

---

**Update**:  ctrl-break does work for me in Python when ctrl-c does not, during a call to a DLL function in an infinite loop.